# How to do make 2 layers of text on iPhone with different contents

Tags: iphone

I want to produce same effect like [2 text layerImage](https://sites.google.com/site/cocoamydarling/pics/444px-TEXTsize2Xtwext.png.png?attredirects=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems obvious, so I'm not sure I understand your question, but... can't you just use two UILabels, one above the other, and apply different formatting to them?

Comment: Thanks :) actually first I tried with HTML then I implemented this UIlabel concept. It works fine.

Comment: Then please feel free to accept the answer as correct (click the tick).